# API fetch call is not processed trough onEdit trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying something out in Google Sheets and Google Scripts to fetch some API calls from ergast.com.
I have reached the point that I have managed to capture an overview of the F1 seasons (years) in an array and present this via a drop-down menu in the Spreadsheet.
The next thing that needs to happen is that when a year has been selected from the dropdown list, another API call must take place and all races of the relevant year will be retrieved.
To achieve this I use a simple trigger -> onEdit(e). In the handling of onEdit(e) I call a function that then handles the API call containing the selected year.
I use concatenating techniques to construct the API call URL. Only the program stops when the API call is executed.
The strange thing is that when I place the composed API call directly in the browser, it works well.

I've read somewhere that simple triggers don't work when authorization coms in play, so I've tried it with an installable trigger. The installable trigger is called when a F1-season is chosen from the dropdown list, but the event object is now passed into the function so the function stops immediately.

I've tried everything i could find, but for know I'm stuck and don't now which direction to go.
Some help would be very appreciated.
Below the script for the onEdit(e) function (which I tried to make it an installable trigger function, but that didn't work also)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const spreadSheet = e.source;
  const sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  const column = range.getColumn();
  const row = range.getRow();
  const seasonValue = e.value;

  // execute when new season is selected
  if (sheetName == 'SetRaceFilter' && column == 1 && row == 2) {
    sheet.getRange(raceChoiceCell).setValue([seasonValue]);
    giveMessage('sheetname: ' + sheetName + ', column: ' + column + ', row: ' + row + 'Season: ' + seasonValue);
    
    // fill raceschedule array
    getRaceSchedule(seasonValue);
    
    
  }
}
```

And below the handling of the call for the API call

```
function getRaceSchedule(_seasonValue) {
  const limit = 30;
  //seasonValue = '1965';
  const F1_RaceScheduleURL = 'https://ergast.com/api/f1/' + _seasonValue + '.json?limit=' + limit + '&offset=0';
  giveMessage('API URL: ' + F1_RaceScheduleURL);

  const responseRaceSchedule = UrlFetchApp.fetch(F1_RaceScheduleURL);
  giveMessage('API URL responsecode: ' + responseRaceSchedule.getResponseCode);
  const dataAsText = responseRaceSchedule.getContentText();
  const data = JSON.parse(dataAsText);
  const totalRaces = data.MRData.total;
  const raceSchedule = data.MRData.RaceTable.Races;
  giveMessage(totalRaces);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < totalRaces; i++) {
    RaceSchedule[i] = [];
    RaceSchedule[i][0] = raceSchedule[i].round;
    RaceSchedule[i][1] = raceSchedule[i].raceName;
    RaceSchedule[i][2] = raceSchedule[i].Circuit.circuitName;
  }

  //fill the dropdownlist for the raceschedule
  fillRacescheduleDropdown();
}

function fillRacescheduleDropdown() {
  var keuzeCell = sheet.getRange(raceChoiceCell);
  var keuzeRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(RaceSchedule).build();
  keuzeCell.setDataValidation(keuzeRule);
}
```

BTW-1, the giveMessage() function calls are there just for testing purposes for myself.
BTW-2, I'm from the Netherlands, so some of the variable choices may seem a bit strange for you.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: If you are using `onEdit` as a simple trigger, unfortunately, in the current stage, UrlFetchApp cannot be used with the simple trigger. So, please use the installable trigger. At that time, please rename the function name from `onEdit` to other and install the OnEdit trigger as the installable trigger. Please be careful about this.